# Golang : How to read and process request body in chunks and set it back again in request body without loading it as a whole in memory?

Tags: go, io, buffer

We have a go webserver, where we are trying to read the request body content in chunk to process something. However, the request will have to be forwarded after the work is done and hence the request body will have to be reset again. Since, there is no way it can be read multiple times from request.body without resetting it, we are using a Wrapper Reader object, which reads in chunk and in parallel write it to a buffer. At the end of the processing, we add this buffer to the request body again. But since the buffer end up loading the whole content, this is a problem if the content is very large.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handleRequest)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func handleRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    maxSize := int64(1000000)
    b := bytes.Buffer{}
    b.Write(make([]byte, 0, maxSize))

    reader := MyReader{
        r:       req.Body,
        buf:     b,
        size:    0,
        maxSize: maxSize,
    }

    err := Validate(&reader)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    r := reader.GetBuffer()
    fmt.Println(len(r.Bytes()))
    req.Body = io.NopCloser(&r)

    //pass the body back for the next handler!
}

type MyReader struct {
    r       io.Reader
    buf     bytes.Buffer
    size    int64
    maxSize int64
}

func (rd *MyReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = rd.r.Read(p)
    if n > 0 {
        rd.size = rd.size + int64(n)
        if n, err := rd.buf.Write(p[:n]); err != nil {
            return n, err
        }
    }
    return n, err
}

func (rd *MyReader) GetBuffer() bytes.Buffer {
    return rd.buf
}

func Validate(reader *MyReader) error {
    //Get standard json decoder
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(reader)

    for {
        //decode next token
        t, err := decoder.Token()
        //Validate the token - should not throw any error
        if err == io.EOF {
            return nil
        }

        if err != nil {
            return errors.New("Some error")
        }
        fmt.Println(t)
        //processing being done on the token
    }

}
```

Is there a way to avoid the buffer and stream the content back to the request body without reading it in the memory ?

Comment: You can stream what you reed directly, use an io.TeeReader as you seem to know. Just don't buffer but send downstream directly.

Comment: @Volker The problem is that TeeReader needs a writer object. But in this case, we want to reset it to the request body itself, so that the next processing units can read from the body again.

Comment: Ah,. I understand. You simply cannot do this. This is not how time works in this universe. You _either_ have to stream, _or_ you have to buffer.

Comment: What you're describing is that you want to stream the response, and then "stream" it again without having stored it anywhere? The only logical way to do this would be to process the stream concurrently as suggested with `io.TeeReader` and connect the writer to another reader with a pipe, but your current design of serially processing the data and "pass the body back for the next handler" is not possible.

Comment: You want to stream the content back to the request body without buffering it in memory? Write it to two different destinations simultaneously. One destination would be your processing logic, and the other would be the original request body.

Comment: @JishanShaikh not sure if I understood your reply. Could you please explain with some examples ?